# How to include large string array resources in an application?

Tags: java, android

I am developing a dictionary app where users can download vocabulary through an API. But I don't want to make my app look empty until they searched for their first word. So I have managed to arrange all the words with their definitions as string array and thought of displaying them as a list.

The problem here is that as I stored vocabulary with their definitions the string array gets too long that the android studio wont allow me to store such a huge number of vocabulary items in the resource array. Also by doing so the app size might increase a lot. I saw many offline dictionaries that work without downloading data on their first run. How did they achieve that ?

Any idea is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Are you try sql lite for offline data?

Comment: Download the dummy data on the first run of your app.

Comment: Yeah I can try Room Api to store but how do I display such a long list on the first run without making my user to wait for a long time while downloading through internet

Comment: So dummy data is something that is displayed partially while the original data is being downloaded in background ? @AjayKS

Comment: that is i mentioned @Ramu

Answer (score 0):

You should create and Offline database like the SQlite database. Storing Big amounts of data in the string array is not an efficient way here.

[This link may help you.](https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Or you can search for other offline databases.

Comment: Thank You ,but database is helpful to store data accessed from either through internet or through user input and then store it . How do I store data from nowhere on the first run of my app without downloading from internet.

Comment: You can run a script of commands in beginning to insert the data in the table when installing the app. Do this while installation. After which you will have data in the app. Insert values in the onCreate method of your SQLiteOpenHelper

Answer (score 0):

For offline dictionary, you can store data into CSV file then import CSV file into your android studio project, either you can directly read content from it or you can insert into sqlite.